# Dynamically add dimensions to crossfilter

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, crossfilter

I have a very high dimensional dataset and would like the users to choose the dimensions to filter (add them to the crossfilter). I understand that dimensions can not be removed. Are there any recommendations as to how adding dimensions/filters could be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just use the field's name as a variable in the dimension function.

I do stuff like this in my app.  x is a property of the dataset that contains an array of the dimension column names.

```
var volume = crossfilter(data.get("rows"));

_.each(data.get("x"), function(x, i) {
  new Chart.View({
    field: x,
    el: $(".chart").eq(i),
    model: volume.dimension(function(d) { return d[x]; })
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

crossfilter has a [dimension.dispose()](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_dispose) function now.

Comment: i tried that but could not get it to work `paymentsByTotal Object {}
paymentsByTotal.dispose()
Object {}
paymentsByTotal
Object {}` it was still there after disposing it [here](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_groupAll)